# Texture painting backface culling option doesn't work while symmetry on

Tags: texture-painting

When I try to paint onto a texture while symmetry on any axis is turned on the backface culling option just doesn't work. Is there anything I could have accidentally turn on or off? Because in the new .blend file everything seems to work correctly.

Here I've made a video to make it more clear: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fx4lJ6H8iFlJNnN6rUsIaGaXrech_nWX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, which version are you using ?

Comment: You might have enabled/disabled display back-face culling on accident for your viewport contrary to what you are going for.

Comment: @Gorgious hello, it's 2.92.0

Comment: @RandomPanda, I don't beleive this to be the problem because i check the backface culling checkbox in active tool and workspace settings tab while in texture paint mode.